# Neo4j plus Cakephp Query time?

Tags: cakephp, neo4j

I'm using Everyman library for using Cakephp with Neo4j.I want to find out the time it is taking for each query?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no EventDispatcher mechanism where you can hook to, btw you can handle this simply with microtime(true) before and after sending your query.

```
$start = microtime(true); 
// you send your query 
$end = microtime(true); 
$diff = $end-$start; 
echo 'query sent in '.$diff.' seconds';
```